# dynamic select box at load webpage

Tags: jquery, select, dynamic

Now I have a static select box, something like this:

```
<label>Select name: </label>
<select id="option" onchange="optionSelected();">
    <option value="-1">=== Select name ===</option>
    <option value="1">Name 1</option>
    <option value="2">Name 2</option>  
    <option value="0">All names</option>  
</select>
```

But I want that number of options could be changed. I have a file with data and webpage loads it during loading. So I now the info I want to show and the number of options. This info will not change. If it is changed, the changes just will be shown the next time webpage is loaded. I have the info in one array, so I can make a for to take all names and using length property, know the size.

I checked some tutorials about ajax but I don't understand them very well. I am using jquery in my webpage.

How can I do it? English is not my first languaje and I don't know the correct words to search in google, I always find many tutorials but not about what I need.

Comment: you could create a select box on the sucess of Ajax by getting the values from db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi [this](http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using.html) is the basic example of creating a dynamic select box from database using ajax. It may useful for you

Comment: This is what I needed. Thanks I will read! Just to delete the second listbox and understand what to do with first. Is it not possible to do with javscript instead with php?

Comment: then how do you fetch the data? u need any one of server side for the dynamic data .